# Laravel echo server client not receiving event

Tags: laravel, socket.io, laravel-echo

I have a small Laravel Echo Server setup using this package (https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server). I have the following setup:

```
// app.js

import Echo from "laravel-echo";

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://vaprobash.dev:6001'
});

window.Echo.channel('documents-sharing')
    .listen("Api\\DocumentShared", (event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

.

```
// server.js
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var Redis = require('ioredis');
var redis = new Redis();

http.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000');
});

redis.subscribe('documents-sharing', function(err, count) {
    console.log("subscribed " + count);
});

redis.on('message', function(channel, message) {
    message = JSON.parse(message);

    console.log('Message Received: ', channel, message);

    console.log(io.to(channel).emit(message.event, message.data));
});
```

.

```
// laravel-echo-server.json
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "986bb8954bb1e2e9",
            "key": "58ca6a205718590ad5fd88a1afc1877c"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port": "6379",
            "host": "localhost"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": ""
}
```

.

```
// DocumentShared.php
class DocumentShared implements ShouldBroadcast, ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use SerializesModels, InteractsWithSockets;
    /**
     * @var User
     */
    public $user;
    /**
     * @var Resource
     */
    public $resource;
    /**
     * @var Share
     */
    public $share;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @param User $user
     * @param Resource $resource
     * @param Share $share
     */
    public function __construct(User $user, Resource $resource, Share $share)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->resource = $resource;
        $this->share = $share;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel("documents-sharing");
    }
}
```

.

```
// app.blade.php
<script src="{{ asset('js/socket.io.min.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ asset('js/home.js') }}"></script>
```

After that I run:

```
gulp watch
redis-server
node server.js
laravel-echo-server start
php artisan queue:listen
```

When the `/notify` route is hit, I fire the event.

```
Route::get('notify', function() {
    $user = User::first();
    $resource = Resource::first();
    $share = Share::first();

    event(new DocumentShared($user, $resource, $share));

    return 'done';
});
```

I can see the server has received the event and it didn't show on the queue.

[terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4jYx.png)

Comment: Do you see something happening Redis with the `monitor` command?

Comment: Yes, The event received correctly. I think that this is something on the front-end or I'm missing something!

Comment: How about changing `window.Echo.channel()` to `Echo.channel()` ?

Comment: Nothing happens. Does the code seem correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the client side couldn't connect to the server because the port wasn't responding. Ironically, I just removed the `host` key from the `laravel-echo-server.json` config file and re-run the server. Everything worked like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading to "socket.io-client": "2.3.0" if you are using a more recent version. This fixed it for me after days of searching for a solution.